# Avoid evaluation of multiplication by 1 in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to avoid multiplication by 1 to be evaluated in sympy. How do I achieve this?

I do not understand why, say, multiplication by 0 can be unevaluated, while multiplication by 1 is always evaluated.

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol,Mul
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> Mul(1,x,evaluate=False)
x
>>> Mul(0,x,evaluate=False)
0*x
```

Comment: is the end goal just printing or you want the expression to be evaluated later on?

Comment: I have written a kind of code generator that parses many terms, assuming they are on the form of Mul(number, something). Of course, I could modify the parser, but I still wonder, and I believe the correct behavior should be that Mul(1,x,evaluate=False) becomes a Mul with args = (1,x).

Answer (score 3):

This is being worked on in https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/13188. Currently, 1 (for Muls) and 0 (for Adds) are automatically removed even if evaluate=False. If you just want to parse something as (number, foo) you can use `expr.as_coeff_Mul()`, e.g. `(1+x).as_coeff_Mul() -> (1, 1 + x)`.